# Spring MVC - what is url path info?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to know what is a url path info?

For example in

> **http://myserver:8080/servletname/handlermethod**

Is it the whole path including server name:

> **http://myserver:8080/servletname/handlermethod**

or is it just

**/servletname/handlermethod**

Comment: What happens when you call getPathInfo()? What does it return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getPathInfo()` according to the doc:

> Returns any extra path information associated with the URL the client
>   sent when it made this request. The extra path information follows the
>   servlet path but precedes the query string and will start with a "/"
>   character.

so in your example it will return `/handlermethod`

If you want to have `/servletname/handlermethod` you should use `getRequestURI()`.

`getRequestURL()` will return the full URL made by the client (except string parameters).

Answer (score 2):

The path info in Spring MVC may imply for the info sent via a URL. In a Spring MVC Controller you can easily set a request mapping which include a variable value place holder which is bound to an argument with `@PathVariable` annotation in the method signature - related to the request mapping. For eaxmple:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{userId}")  
public ModelAndView getUserByPathVariable(@PathVariable Long userId, HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) { 
        System.out.println("Got request param: " + userId);
```

You take a look here for a more detailed example: [Spring MVC Controller Example](http://www.commonj.com/blogs/2012/06/01/spring-mvc-3-tutorial-passing-request-parameters-to-controllers/)