# In IIS 7.5, trailing uri after the / returns a page even though it should be a 404

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I am running IIS 7.5. I have url rewrite disabled.

A visit to  www.mydomain.com/index.html is a sucessful load.

However if I go to www.mydomain.com/index.html/testcontent, this is not a 404. Instead it loads the index.html but all of the links are now relative. Testcontent does not actually exist.

I have no idea how this is happening. I've setup another machine and tested it and it should be a 404.

IIS is not treating index.html as a directory if it sees the trailing slash.

This is not mvc but static html with iis.

Comment: https://users.cs.fiu.edu/~downeyt/webdev/path.info.html `/testcontent` is treated as path info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC - what is url path info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921666/spring-mvc-what-is-url-path-info)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.   testcontent is treated as path info. how can i get it to be  404 instead?

Comment: We have the static html handler. We use static html, aspx, and asp.

Comment: a valid URL should never be responded with 404.

Comment: i setup IIS on my local machine as a test and when I do the same type of url,    localhost.com/index.html/testcontent  --- i get a 404.  any suggestions???      mydomain.com/index.html/testcontent --- shuld be a 404 because testcontent does not exist.